# Как получить из потока массив байт, пересланный через сокеты?

Tags: c#, сокет

Нужно получить на выходе такой же массив типа byte[], что и отправлен. Есть пример с получением строковой переменной, как поступить с byte?

код отправки:

```
sender.Connect(ipEndPoint);
int bytesSent = sender.Send(message1);//message1-массив байт
```

код на приеме:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);// сейчас пишет в строковую переменную data. Как записать в массив байт?
```

Comment: GetString не используйте, вот вам и массив байт

Comment: А что использовать? Как получить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот же Ваш массив, Вы используете его как буфер на 1024 байт:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
```

Вот представьте, что **bytes** -- это ведро на 1кБайт. Здесь Вы опускаете его в колодезь  (сокет) и ждёте, пока что-то туда попадет:

```
int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
```

После чего достаете, и в **bytesRec** имеете значение величины того, сколько же байт набралось в ведро.

Ничто не мешает Вам использовать этот буферный массив дальше, зная величину его заполнения. Вот только аккуратней: если захотите вытащить кое-что больше, за 1кБайт, то такого "ведра" Вам не хватит :)

Comment: Видимо речь идет о TCP и здесь важно понимать, что количество байт, полученных Receive может быть меньше, чем послано в Send. 

TCP соединение - это поток байт ("труба"), а не последовательность пакетов, каждый из которых, отправляется одном Send-ом. Следующие Receive дочитают накапливающиеся в "трубе" байты.

--

Реально, при передаче массива нужно знать, сколько байт передается и на принимающей стороне считывать их в цикле. 

При этом лучше читать min(размер приемного буфера, осталось прочесть байт).

Comment: Спасибо большое, я понял, что данные принимаются потоком.Проблема решена!